# Utilizing Redis for transferring load

Tags: python, asynchronous, redis

I have been looking at a python [tutorial](https://realpython.com/blog/python/flask-by-example-implementing-a-redis-task-queue/), and it is using Redis to move the processing load of some text from the webapp server to another process(redis). Although, visiting the Redis website,and other online resources Redis is presented as a type of data store.

Does the tutorial use it correctly?

> Is it a valid use case, to move load to a redis server for heavy
>   processing, from the webapp server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes.

Redis itself is an advance key-value storage. But the tutorial is not about using pure Redis but [RQ](http://python-rq.org/) which is one of the simplest queueing libraries. RQ is not Redis but uses it.